# vb The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net

I have tried to close after creating a file : `Create(LogFile).Close()` but its still not working. The error is in this line:

```
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\AsrahLim\Desktop\LogFile.txt", s, True)
```

below is my full code:

```
 Dim Path As String = "C:\Users\AsrahLim\"
            Dim target As String = "C:\Users\AsrahLim\Google Drive"

            If e.FullPath <> target Then
                Dim LogFile As String = "C:\Users\AsrahLim\Desktop\LogFile.txt"
            If Not Exists(LogFile) Then
                Create(LogFile).Close()
            End If
             End If

 If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created Then
                WriteLine("File has been created- " & e.FullPath & vbCrLf)
            FileClose()
            End If

            If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed Then
                WriteLine("File has been changed- " & e.FullPath & vbCrLf)
            FileClose()
        End If

            If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed Then
            WriteLine("File has been renamed- " & e.FullPath & vbCrLf)
            FileClose()
            End If

        Dim s As String = ReadLines()

 Public Function ReadLines() As String
            Dim s As String = Console.ReadLine()
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\AsrahLim\Desktop\LogFile.txt", s, True)
        Return s

        End Function

        Public Sub WriteLine(ByVal s As String)
            Console.WriteLine(s)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\AsrahLim\Desktop\LogFile.txt", s, True)

        End Sub
```

FileSystemWatcher's code:

```
Public watcher As FileSystemWatcher
    Sub Main()
    Do


        'Watch Files
        Dim watcher As New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher("C:\Users\AsrahLim\", "*.docx")


        ' Add event handlers.
        AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
        AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf OnChanged
        AddHandler watcher.Renamed, AddressOf OnChanged


        With watcher
            ' Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = True
            watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Created Or WatcherChangeTypes.Changed Or WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed)

            watcher.Filter = "*.docx"
            ' Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and the renaming of files or directories. 
            watcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.DirectoryName)


        End With
    Loop Until False
    End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to call `File.Create()` at all. It is only a shorthand for opening a `FileStream`. If the file doesn't exist then `WriteAllText` (or any other method for that matter) will create it. -- `FileClose()` is also an unnecessary call. It is a legacy VB6 function and is in no way related to what you're doing now, so you should remove those calls too.

Comment: Is this process multithreaded? Or are you calling `WriteLine` from other places outside your `FileSystemWatcher`?

Comment: @VisualVincent its not multithread. And I didn't call `WriteLine` outside my `FileSystemWatcher` too. I have edited my question, I add my`FileSystemWatcher` code.